# Flash: How to lower background music when other sound effects play?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

*I am using sound files from the library, not URLs.*

I am making a soundboard and have a button that plays background music. The reason I have a button instead of automatically playing on load is that there are a few different background musics to choose from, each with their own button.

I also have several other buttons that play sounds. I want the background music volume to lower to something like 0.3 while other sounds are playing. I believe I need to create a variable like soundCount that goes up when a sound plays, and decreases when the sound finishes playing (so that if there are multiple sounds playing at once, the background music won't go back to normal until the count is at 0).

What's the best way to set this up? I made the soundCount variable but I'm having trouble creating an event listener for when sound effect finishes playing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the volume of a sound in AS3, you need to use the `SoundChannel` and `SoundTransform` classes:

```
var backgroundMusic:Sound = // Assuming you've loaded a sound

var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
myChannel = backgroundMusic.play();

var myTransform = new SoundTransform();
myChannel.soundTransform = myTransform;
```

Keep track of total sounds in the background by incrementing your count during calls to `play` and decrementing during `SOUND_COMPLETE` events.  Add event listeners to other sounds' channels so they can modify `background`'s volume:

```
var totalCurrentSounds:int = 0;

otherSoundChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, otherSoundComplete);
// Make sure this is on a SoundChannel, not the Sound itself.
```

Finally, modify the `SoundTransform`'s `volume` member when the count is 0:

```
function otherSoundComplete(e:Event):void {
    totalCurrentSounds--;
    if (totalCurrentSounds <= 0) 
        myTransform.volume = 0.5;
}
```

Comment: Is there any event that listens for when *any* sound plays or finishes playing? The reason is because I have something like 50 sound effect buttons and it would be tedious to create a sound channel for each of them.

Comment: I could help further if we could see some more of your project's structure.  There are some easy ways to do this but we'd need to see how you have your buttons and click-to-play logic organized.

Comment: Right now the buttons play the sound files directly, now using actionscript. i.e. I double clicked on each button, set the "Down" keyframe to play its individual sound. Can I make a generic function that plays any button based on an instance variable name or Linkage Class, something like that?

Comment: It will be easiest to help if you could update your question's body with the code you currently have as well as indicating where in the .fla project that code exists.

Comment: What I'm saying is, besides what you just posted, I have no code. I haven't used action script yet to play sounds from the buttons, I've just double clicked on each button, clicked "Down" in the frame and selected a sound file from my library in the "Sound" dropdown box. I realize I'll probably have to scrap that and play all sound effect sounds in actionscript to do what I want, so I'm looking for help now to create a generic "playSoundEffect" function that can hopefully somehow work for all my buttons.